# xperf -providers doesn't show the name of TraceLoggingProvider defined by TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER

Tags: windows, etw, xperf, trace-logging

I follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tracelogging/tracelogging-native-quick-start) to set up a `TraceLoggingProvider` in my application.

During the application runs, I try to use `xperf -providers` to see if my user event provider is there:
I cannot see the name I defined in `TRACELOGGING_DEFINE_PROVIDER` but only the defined GUID is shown. Is it intended?

Instead following another [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tracelogging/tracelogging-record-and-display-tracelogging-events) with WPRP file, I just use `xperf -start` to capture events. And the same: I can only use GUID as parameter, not the defined name! is it also intended?

Anyway, at the end I can view the result properly in WPA and the defined **name** of my user event provider is visible.

are all my observaton intended?

Comment: does **wpr.exe  -providers** show it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 wpr does not show either GUID or name from my provider....  probably because I do not use wprp profile..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you use in the C++ code is unrelated to the display name on your pc.

You'd have a displayed name (instead of GUID) if this was a manifested installed provider, but TraceLogging isn't manifested (at least, not in the classical sense - an impromptu manifest is embedded into the image, and sent in the messages).

Comment: thanks, it makes sense now. Is there some document about this?

Comment: This is a nice place to start
https://ticehurst.com/2019/11/04/manifest-free-etw-in-cpp.html
This also has useful links
https://github.com/jdu2600/Windows10EtwEvents